# Is it possible to use a trigger to modify a value before it's inserted or updated?

Tags: triggers, teradata

We have several apps putting empty strings into a non-nullable database field which is causing issues with other applications that are expecting a value.  What I'd like to do for now is turn the empty string into a null before an insert or update so that Teradata throws `Column 'whatever' is NOT NULL` which would result in an exception being thrown in the application.

**Edit**

I removed my old coneptual SQL which was incorrect and replaced it with new SQL that actually works, but only partially.

```
Replace trigger mydb.inserttest
before insert ON mydb.test
referencing new row as newrow
for each row
(
    set newrow.name = case when newrow.name = '' then null else newrow.name end;
);
```

This appears to replace the empty string with a null before the insert.  However, it also seems to not throw an exception when a UPI is violated.  For example, I have the following table:

```
create table mydb.test
(name varchar(20) not null)
unique primary index (name);
```

I can execute this statement successfully the first time:

```
insert into mydb.mytable ('joe');
```

It tells me `INSERT completed.  1 rows processed`.  However, if I run it again, it simply tells me `INSERT completed.  0 rows processed`.  What you'd normally expect is a `Duplicate unique prime key error`, but the trigger seems to somehow suppress the exception which causes the calling .NET application to die silently when the UPI constraint is violated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a check constraint?

```
create table mydb.test
(name varchar(20) not null, check (name <> ''))
unique primary index (name);
```